# How to calculate angle of rotation of a rectangle, given its 4 points

Tags: algorithm, octave, bounding-box

I have a set of 2D points. I did eigenvectors estimation of its covariance. Made transformation to new basis and found the bounding box there. 
For simplicity giving code in octave below.
Points are given as: points variable with shape of Nx2

```
mycov = cov(points);
[V, E] = eig(mycov);
new_basis_points = V*points';
```

Then in the code I estimate max and min values for each axis and make four points set:

```
points = [[minX, minY], 
          [minX, maxY],
          [maxX, minY],
          [maxX, maxY]];
```

Now I transform back to old basis:

```
old_basis_bounding_box = V'*points';
```

These calculations are correct, I get four corner points in old basis. But now I want to estimate the angle of rotation of the rectangle between its side and X axis.

The problem is, that the order of points in `old_basis_bounding_box` is not defined. So I'm not sure which two points to select to make angle estimation.

How should I proceed?

Comment: So you get result as `Fi + k * Pi / 2`?

Comment: You have the transformation matrix...

Answer (score 3):

[image: Illustration]

I believe the angle `alpha` (marked green in the image) is what you are looking for. Assuming the lowest point of the rectangle is `O(0, 0)`, this angle can be easily calculated as cos<sup>-1</sup>(a/sqrt(a^2+b^2)), where `B(a,b)` is the point with lowest positive [slope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope). As of D ≠ O (where D is the point with the lowest y-axis coordinate), just move the whole thing by the vector `OD` so that D = O.

Don't forget to separately handle the case when the rectangle already aligned to the axis, when you may get division by zero.

My pseudo-code:

```cpp
    struct Point
    {
        double x, y, angle;
        Point (double x, double y): x(x), y(y) {}
    };

    bool SortByY (Point a, Point b)
    {
        return a.y < b.y;
    }

    bool SortByAngle (Point a, Point b)
    {
        return a.angle < b.angle;
    }

    double GetRotationAngle(vector<Point> points)
    {
        sort (points.begin(), points.end(), SortByY);

        // If there are 2 points lie on the same y-axis coordinates, simply return 0
        if  (points[0].y == points[1].y) return 0;

        Point D = points[0];

        for (int i=1; i<4; i++)
        {
            // Move the whole thing by vector OD
            double a = points[i].x -= D.x;
            double b = points[i].y -= D.y;

            // Keep in mind that in C++, the acos function returns value in radians, you may need to convert to degrees for your purposes.
            points[i].angle = acos(a / sqrt(a*a+b*b));
        }

        sort (points.begin()+1, points.end(), SortByAngle);
        return points[1].angle;
    }
```

Comment: What if it doesn't give you rectangle with 90 degree between it's sizes?